# component wise indexing in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

How can I do component wise Indexing in Matlab ?
given

```
N =

 1     2
 2     3
 3     1
L =

     0    2.0000    2.8284
2.0000         0    2.0000
2.8284    2.0000         0
```

I want to extract element of L that are given by rows of N
that is 
[L(1,2),L(2,3),L(3,1)] = [2.0, 2.0, 2.8284]

We can easily do that using a for loop

```
Lele=zeros(3,1);
for i = 1:3
   Lele(i) = L(N(i,1),N(i,2)); 
end
```

How can we do this in a vectorized way using indexing technique ?.
in other words how can we use the row of matrix as index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract linear indices using [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) and then use them to extract the required elements i.e.

```
Lele = L(sub2ind(size(L), N(:,1), N(:,2)));
```